# Show correct answers and points in automultiplechoice

Tags: auto-multiple-choice

While I am creating a multiple choice exam with `automultiplechoice` (amc) I would like to directly see in the pdf-preview of my LaTeX editor, which answer is correct and how many points I gave for it.

Is there some option for the package to show the solution (i.e., correct answers, points given for each choice and eventually an explanation.

While typing the LaTeX code for the exam it would be very convenient to directly get feedback from the pdf preview if I have entered the points correctly and if the explanations are displayed correctly.

In other words: Is there some equivalence of `\documentclass[answers]{exam}` or `\printanswers` for amc without using the exam document class?

<sub>This would be especially helpful at our university, where multiple people create an exam together via Overleaf and multiple people have to check it before printing.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is done automatically in the GUI without touch the LaTeX code directly. Just choose the type of document in the button "Documents" or the like (sorry, I am watching it translated to Spanish):

[image: the button]

See also Preferences (the whrench icon) → Document to ensure that produce the three document types at once, without modify the .tex source. One of these is the *corrected* version:

[image: mwe]

In case that you cannot use the GUI, from the manual, one of the package options is:

> `answers`: produces the corrected version of the MCQ test, not the test sheet itself.

So, in short:

```
\usepackage[answers,...]{automultiplechoice}
```

Code of the screenshot without using the GUI:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[answers]{automultiplechoice}
\element{code}{
\begin{question}{sum}
    Check the equation with the correct result. 
    \begin{choices}
        \wrongchoice{$0\times2=2$}
        \wrongchoice{$2\times0=20$}
        \wrongchoice{$2+2=22$}
        \correctchoice{$2+2=4$}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{question}{xyz}
    Real meaning of \emph{several}. 
    \begin{choices}
        \wrongchoice{Many}
        \wrongchoice{A few}
        \wrongchoice{Various}
        \wrongchoice{A handful of}
        \correctchoice{Three (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
} % <------ end of element
\begin{document}
\onecopy{1}{\insertgroup{code}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super, this is basically what I wanted. If it could also show the `\scoring{...}` for each choice would be even better, so that I can see on one glance in the compiled pdf if I have entered all the scores for all the options correctly, while writing it.